# Changing Cocoa display name in the app?

Tags: cocoa, macos

How do I change the name that shows up above my app in the Dock on OS X? (I've tried renaming the target and renaming my project. And, I've Googled it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further Googling, I've found this:

> "Project" -> "Edit Active Target" -> "Packaging" -> "Product Name"

(It didn't work the first time I tried it though... Odd.)

Comment: Why must I wait two days to answer my own question?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest change BundleName in info plist file of you project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the target you want to rename in the Targets list
2. Wait one second
3. Click again. The target name will get into edit modus.
4. Rename the target.
5. Press Enter.