# Xcode - How to change the display name of an app for macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos-sierra

The product name of the app is the name of your app as it will appear to customers and you choose it in the Xcode Assistant when starting a new project, but what if you would like to change it?

It seems a trivial question but I tried searching and I find old answers like this one [Changing Cocoa display name in the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885076/changing-cocoa-display-name-in-the-app) (seven years ago) or this one [How to change the name of a Mac application in the build settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420115/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-mac-application-in-the-build-settings) which assumes you have a MainMenu.xib file, or answers that refer to iPhone as for example this answer (nine years ago) [How to change the name of an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238980/how-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app) or this [Apple's Technical note for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1823/_index.html).

Because many things may have changed in Xcode since seven or more years and macOS is different from iOS, I'm afraid to create some trouble, or to change the name that appears in some parts, but forget the old name in another place.

What is the correct way to change the name that the user sees in an app for Mac?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There are several ways to change the name of the app, after you have created the project:

1. You can rename the target (Double click on the name) because by default Xcode uses the target name as product's name (see next screenshot).
   [image: Target name]
2. You can set the product name directly in the build settings or via xcconfig files. I actually prefer this way because you can create different names for different build configurations, e.g., "MyApp Debug", "MyApp Beta", "MyApp". So just replace the `$(TARGET_NAME)` with the name of your app.
   [image: Build settings before]
   [image: Build settings after]

Comment: This is a great answer. Works for iOS as well and is much nicer than trying to manage plist files. I found that you can't name two targets the same (iOS version and macOS version) so that's where option #2 will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the display name of the app in Finder and at runtime, but *not* its actual file path, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902023/153354) might be what you are looking for. Using the localized app name in that way also affects the app's title as displayed in Notification Center.